# R - Take colnames of dataframe and collect into a formula

Tags: r, string, dataframe, formula

I have the following dataset type in R:

```
col1   col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
1       h       s       h       s       s       l
2       l       m       s       l       h       s
3       m       h       l       l       h       l
4       vh      s       h       l       s       s
5       vl      s       s      vl       s       l
6       m       s       l       h       l       h
7       l       s       l       h       h       h
8       l       s       h       m       s       h
```

where `colX` is the generic column name of the dataframe.

I would like to create a function that, given as input - let's say -
four desired `colX` (for instance, `col1`,`col3`,`col4`,`col7`)
is able to convert as follows:

`col1 + col3 + col4 + col7`

Comment: The final expression just refers to the strings which represent the columns names, I don't need the sum of the values within the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.formula` and `paste`:

```
f <- function(x) as.formula(paste("dependent_variable ~", 
                            paste(colnames(x), collapse="+")))

dat <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(10),
                  col2=rnorm(10),
                  col3=rnorm(10))

f(dat)
#> dependent_variable ~ col1 + col2 + col3
```

Obviously, you just need to change `colnames(x)` to the vector of column names that you want in the formula.